# How to change compiled java code using Java?

Tags: java

I'm need an efficient way to change compiled java code using java. Is there a way to do this? I'm really not sure what would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Really have no clue what you are asking here.

Comment: There are many bytecode manipulation libraries available.

Comment: Do you mean you want to modify bytecode directly?  Or you talking about recompiling something, invoking javac from inside a java program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it requires you to understand [the Java Class File Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html), and to read and write the `.class` file as a set of structured, ordered bytes.

There are bytecode libraries, like BCEL that can assist with some of the details; however, depending on your exact use cases, the libraries may address issues you are not concerned with.

Comment: just decompile it and change.

Comment: @redFIVE While that is an option, sometimes that is not really the best option.  For example, all the JDO enhancers and Aspect oriented toolkits do their stuff without the excessive overhead of going back to source and merging in new source code (and having a second compile phase).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DJ Java Decompiler` or `Cavaj Java Decompiler` to decompile your class

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that however its not advisable edit the .class file as.

If you really interested to edit the same use the below link.

[classeditor.sourceforge.net](http://classeditor.sourceforge.net/)